# Cannot view globally reusable workflows

Tags: sharepoint-designer, designer-workflow

**Background:** I recently inherited a new SP site and have Full Control permissions for it. It is SP2010 / Designer 2010. I want to take a globally reusable workflow (approval), copy it, and and use a slightly modified version of it for managing the approval process of a list form on the new site.

**Problem:** When stepping into SP Designer and navigating to Workflows, I am not able to see any Globally Reusable Workflows. If I instead create a new workflow, the only templates I can pull from are the Three State and Disposition options; again no Approval template or any other globally reusable workflow appear as options.

**Question:** How can I get the globally reusable workflows to appear in designer so I can copy, edit, and reuse their code as necessary?

Comment: As an update: I had my permissions promoted from Full Control to Site Collection Administrator. Still not able to view anything.

Comment: I do not see any globally reusable templates in SP Designer 2010. At Site Collection Features we clicked the Activate button for Workflows and restarted Designer but the workflows still do not appear. (We are using SharePoint Foundation 2010.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the solution I arrived at:

1. Get Site Collection Admin privileges (or contact your admin).
2. Go to **`Site Actions --> Site Settings`**.
3. Look under the **`Site Collection Administration`** section, and then click on the **`Site Collection Features`** link.
4. Scroll to the bottom of page and find the **`Workflows`** row, then click the **`Activate`** button.
5. Restart SharePoint Designer. You can now see Globally Reusable Workflows in the Workflow section. Great job!